# Class hierarchy definition VS (automatically) generated navigational properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, f#, navigation-properties, transitive-closure

What should drive design consideration for the following case ?

Let's say you have Quotes.

A Quote relates to a specific Contract.

I can ***define*** my classes in the following way

```
Contract =
  someproperty  : int

Quote:
  contract : Contract
```

Yet when i navigate I would like, *even if it does **not** exists in my model*, to be able to do

```
myContract.quotes
```

Typically, those properties are generated when using the Entity framework or some other ORM.

But the question of separating the ***definition*** from the ***navigation*** exists in full generality, even when using pure memory only classes.

(I guess one could frame in into generating the transitive closure of the navigation graph, from the subset of links specified at the definition)

My question is : what are the possible practical approach to inherit automatically those navigational properties in FSharp ? I am just a user, and not an framework developper, abnd this is very low level stuff.

[Obviously you can generalize to more complex class hierarchies can be

- A Quote comes from a broker, is of bid or ask nature, has a level, and is valide for a specific contract.
- Contract can be for a certain maturity, say 2013, and refer to a specific company.
- Company has a ticker, etc, etc... ]

Comment: I'd correct this myself but I'm not quite sure what "A Quote comes i valid for a specific Contract." should read.  Do you mean to say "A Quote becomes invalid for a specific Contract"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I've misunderstood; but could you not use an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233211.aspx) to add the ability to navigate this way? You'd still need to call a function to get the quotes for the particular contract, but the helper would exist, which can just call your data provider for a filtered list of quotes for that contact?

Comment: that seems to be a practical and no nonsense idea. as I was (re)picking up programming at the time of the question, I was asking the question in a more general way which is probably not fit for SO anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Hum, interesting question.

According to this [blog post](http://www.thereforesystems.com/creating-entity-data-model-without-a-database-with-entity-framework-4/), you can just use the entity framework to do that in a non-database-backed way. You'll have to handle the persistence yourself.

Or your could try spending a week-end solving this problem yourself with a generic F# solution, but I'd say that EF is good enough here ?

Comment: indeed, but I still have to deal with code annotations, and "id's", which I feel shoud be hidden. Also, I would need source code access to the types, witch I don't have using type providers. That means creating 'wrappers'. nasty.

Comment: Actually, even the Entity Framework does not support this.... cf All the plumbing and code needed for that very basic operation of finding all relatedproducts....  http://books.google.com/books?id=WdRzgaw5tlQC&pg=PA198&lpg=PA198&dq=entity+framework+transitive+closure&source=bl&ots=3WjqLvDCgL&sig=xTioCFV08R6pF55v8tj37EQ-LLE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=gCpRT5tT4rzRBfPW5fwL&ved=0CCMQ6AEwAA